# Problems when trayin to add labrary to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

hi i am trying to add MPAndroidChart to my android studio i tried evrything from file>New >Import Module
and tried to copy it directly to my android studio 
i put this in the

```
include':Libraries:MPChartLib'
```

and this in the dependency

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'   }
```

but i always keep getting this error

[image: error]

please helppp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read follow documentation [github](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
Add the following to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
}
```

Comment: i did and now it says Gradle Dsl not found : 'pply()'

Comment: thanks it works now i think the problem was that i wrote that in the builde.gradle of the project you need to put that in the build.gradle for the app

Answer (score 1):

add or merge this in your build.gradle script.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Comment: can u please give me a simple step by step on how to add this library to ur android project ??